# change title in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I have a tourism site and I want to change the title

The site title is now displayed as follows :

“Activities | San Francisco, USA | My Website title”

to :
“Activities San Francisco, USA | My Website title”

This code is in the template

```
<title> <? php wp_title ('|', true, 'right'); ?> </title>
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Remove the seperater from the parameters. Chnage the function to this:

`<title> <?php wp_title('', true); ?> </title>`

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to set a title is using add_theme_support('title_tag'). This has to be added to the functions.php file. Then use wp_head() inside  tags. Using wp_head(), auto generates the page title in WordPress. Then you can use a filter **document_title_parts** to filter the auto generated title of your wordpress pages. Of course you can use condition logic in side the document_title_parts filter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).